# Clicking a button in IE with VBS when the button has no ID or name and has the same class as another button

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm trying to automate a task in IE using VBS and I need to click the submit button.  There are two submit buttons, a "Search" and a "Phoenetic Search."  Neither button has a value or an id specified and they both have the same class.  The HTML for the buttons is:

```
<td align="left"><button type="button" class="searchAdv" onclick="javascript:postAdvancedSearch()">Search</button><br></td>
<td align="left"><button type="button" class="searchAdv" onclick="javascript:postAdvancedPhoneticSearch()">Phonetic Search</button></td>
```

I have this code so far:

```
Set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application") 
strURL = "http://somewebsite.com"
IE.navigate strURL 
IE.Visible = true   
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4)    
    WScript.Sleep 100    
Loop    
Set searchButton = IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("searchAdv")
```

This grabs both buttons since they are the only ones on the page with that class but now how do I pick out the right button to click.  `searchButton(0 or 1).value` is empty.  What attribute holds the "Search" and "Phoenetic Search" labels for the buttons?  I would think there would be something like `searchButton(0).label` or `.text` or something but I haven't found what works.  How do I grab the right button?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  It was the `innerhtml` attribute.

```
for each button in searchButton
    if instr(button.innerhtml,"Search") then
        button.click
        exit for
    end if
next
```

Comment: That check matches both "Search" *and* "Phonetic Search", because both contain the (sub)string "Search", so the clicked button depends on which one `.getElementsByClassName()` returns first. It's better to use the `innerText` property and compare the full string: `If LCase(Trim(button.innerText)) = "search" Then`. `Trim()` removes leading and trailing spaces from the string, and by using `LCase()` you emulate a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Or by looping through all the links on the page:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
'IE.Visible = 0
IE.navigate "http://<www.YourUrlToPage.net/..>"
While IE.ReadyState < 4 Or IE.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
'(ReadyState:4=Complete,3=Interactive,2=Loaded,1=Loading,0=Uninitialized)

'WScript.Echo IE.Document.title
For Each link in IE.Document.links
  'a=MsgBox("link:" & vbCrLf & " " & link.href & vbCrLf &_
  '         "html:" & vbCrLf &_" " & link.innerhtml & vbCrLf &_
  '         "text:" & vbCrLf &_" " & link.innertext)
  If instr(link.innerhtml,"<check text>") Then
    link.Click
    While IE.ReadyState < 4 Or IE.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

(to activate the MsgBox remove the regarding Single quotes)