# How to click a button in Internet explorer on website that is already open using VBscript

Tags: internet-explorer, button, vbscript, hyperlink

This is the button in IE:

`<button style='font-family: "Segoe UI"; margin-left: 10px;' type="button" ng-click="finish()" ng-disabled="!context.isFinishEnabled">Finish</button>`

But I cant figure out what to do to click it using VBscript, I know how to select the active window:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Zillion RIS - Internet Explorer"
```

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: I would suggest you loop through all buttons on the webpage and try to check its `innerHTML`. It will help you to find the button that contains the text 'Finish'. Then you could click it. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27085653/10309381) for code example.

Comment: I came a little further i nog have the code below but i get an error:
`Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Zillion RIS - Internet Explorer"
Set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
Set searchButton = IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("btn")
for each button in searchButton
    if instr(button.innerhtml,"Finish") then
        button.click
        exit for
    end if
nextIf
Next`
The error says 
Line: 4
Char: 1
Error: Unspecified error
Code: 80004005
Source: (null)